Convert raw bytes image data received from Python into C++ Qt QIcon to be displayed in QStandardItem
I am creating small GUI system and I would like to get an image in the form of raw bytes from Python code and then create QImage/QIcon using those raw bytes. For C++/Python interaction I am using Boost Python.
On Python code side I printed the raw bytes:
b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x00@\x08\x02\x00\x00\x00%\x0b\xe6\x89\x00\x00\x00\x03sBIT\x08\x08\x08\xdb\xe1O\xe0\x00\x00\x00\tpHYs\x00\x00\x0e\xc4\x00\x00\x0e\xc4\x01\x95+\x0e\x1b\x00\x00\x06\xabIDATh\x81\xed\x9aOh\x13O\x14\xc7wv\x93\xdd\xfcQ1\xa9\x8d....
I send them as string from python to the C++ code like:
data.rawBytes = str(thumbnail._raw_bytes)

On C++ side, I extract these bytes in the form of string as:
std::string rawBytes = boost::python::extract<std::string>(obj.attr("rawBytes"));

The above rawBytes received on C++ side is same as the python print above.
Now in the UI code, I try to use these raw bytes to create QIcon like:
std::string rawbytes = data.rawBytes;
QByteArray arr();
arr.append(rawbytes.c_str(), rawbytes.length());
bool flag = pixmap.loadFromData(arr, "PNG");

QStandardItem* item = new QStandardItem(name);
item->setIcon(QIcon(pixmap));

The icon doesn't get displayed in the UI and moreover, the 'flag' returned from pixmap.loadFromData is false which means there is some problem in conversion of the raw bytes. Can someone point out if there needs to be some kind of conversion from python to c++ code to properly render this image on the UI?

Does arr represent PNG encoded image data?  If not then what does it represent?

arr is a QByteArray created from the rawbytes string which is the PNG image data shown in the printed raw bytes data.

"The above rawBytes received on C++ side is same as the python print above." No they're not. str is only to be used for making things printable. You should prefer using the Python buffer protocol to effectively pass a pointer to the Python-managed memory. If you absolutely must use strings to hand over objects, base64-encode them first.

Assuming on the Python side you have
data.rawBytes = thumbnail._raw_bytes

without the str wrapper, and a C++ variable obj referring to data, you can use the Python Buffer protocol like so:
Py_Buffer view = {0};
int ret = PyObject_GetBuffer(obj.attr("rawBytes").ptr(), &view, PyBUF_SIMPLE);
if (ret == -1) {
  // handle error
}

QByteArray arr =
  QByteArray::fromRawData(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(view.buf), view.len);
bool flag = pixmap.loadFromData(arr, "PNG");

PyObject_ReleaseBuffer(&view);

You can of course skip the copying to a QByteArray and read directly from Python buffer:
pixmap.loadFromData(reinterpret_cast<uchar *>(view.buf), view.len, "PNG"));


This worked like a charm. Thanks a lot. Out of curiosity, if we were to use base64-encode method, how would that work? Do you mean encode the str(thumbnail._raw_bytes) string on python side and then decode the same using some api on C++ side?

On the Python side: base64.b64encode(thumbnail._raw_bytes), on the Qt side QByteArray::fromBase64(str)
